# How to open onboard in python in linux

Tags: python

I don't know how to reply to your message（Aran-Fey），terminal is ok.
the question is: when i select general user and type "onboard",the function is ok.But select root user and type "onboard",the function is error
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
I use the newly installed linux（16.04） in the virtual machine.
Open the command window and type onboard.

This is ok.
When I use python to call os.system('/usr/bin/onboard'),The beginning is ok.
When I restart the virtual machine，I get an error:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/???# python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.system('/usr/bin/onboard')
05:32:46.070 WARNING OnboardGtk: D-Bus session bus unavailable  Onboard will start with reduced functionality. Single-instance check, D-Bus service and hover click are disabled.
05:32:46.079 WARNING Config: mousetweaks GSettings schema not found, mousetweaks integration disabled.

(onboard:3157): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(onboard:3157): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(onboard:3157): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(onboard:3157): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: The connection is closed

(onboard:3157): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_connection_register_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(onboard:3157): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_connection_register_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(onboard:3157): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_connection_get_unique_name: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/onboard", line 36, in <module>
    ob = Onboard()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Onboard/OnboardGtk.py", line 146, in __init__
    self.init()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Onboard/OnboardGtk.py", line 247, in init
    self.service_keyboard = ServiceOnboardKeyboard(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Onboard/OnboardGtk.py", line 811, in __init__
    super(ServiceOnboardKeyboard, self).__init__(dbus.SessionBus(), self.PATH)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 211, in __new__
    mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/_dbus.py", line 100, in __new__
    bus = BusConnection.__new__(subclass, bus_type, mainloop=mainloop)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 122, in __new__
    bus = cls._new_for_bus(address_or_type, mainloop=mainloop)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
256`enter code here`
```

Comment: So the error only occurs if you use `os.system`? It doesn't occur if you type the command into a terminal?

Comment: Is [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=249041) related to your question

Comment: @Aran-Fey  terminal is ok